# Nicole Oserme and mathematics of Middle Ages

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Does anybody know of any textbooks that discuss some of the work by Nicole Oserme and in the period of the Middle Ages ?

Comment: speeling incorrect https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Oresme/